# Git contributions not showing my commits only the create repo and pull requests on GitHub

Tags: git, github, git-commit

I went through your following article https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile/ for contribution not being shown on my profile.

To say the least.

I am pushing commits on my own repository master branch and I can see those commits on GitHub but they aren’t being added in my contribution.
Its been more than 24 hours and in multiple directories. No, None of the repository I am pushing my commits are forked.

They are no contributors to the given repository so I can push commits.
Also checked my user name and email they match

[Question:] Can someone tell me what wrong I could be doing? or how to fix it?

My git repository is: https://github.com/assilfarhat